# How to parse a string to match a pattern in c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I need to capture a substring for each item in a list of filepaths. The list I am looping through does not exist in the file system, so I cannot use the  Path class. I want to begin parsing from the end of the string and stop once I reach the first "/". I've tried  .Substring() and .Split() but neither method appears to have the ability to match a specified pattern or read from right to left.

Example: Some Directory/Some SubDirectory/SomeFile.pdf

I want to capture "SomeFile.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Path.GetFileName(path)
```

Using the Path class is the simplest, most correct and secure way. However, if you would like to parse from the end of the string, or from right to left, one way is to reverse the string and parse it.

Reverse the string, search for "/", get the substring, reverse your substring, and you have what you were looking for.

Example: Call the method GetFileNameFromPath with your path, and it will print SomeFile.pdf.

```
using System;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = "Some Directory/Some SubDirectory/SomeFile.pdf";
        string fileName = GetFileNameFromPath(path);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
    public static string GetFileNameFromPath(string path)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        path = path.ReverseString();
        fileName = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(@"/"));
        fileName = fileName.ReverseString();
        return fileName;
    }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string ReverseString(this string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were going to do it this way, wouldn't it be easier to just use linq and do `path.Split('/').Last()`?

Comment: Why do you try to implement an inefficient `GetFileNameFromFullPath` if there's already a [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.71).aspx) out of the box since .NET 1.1?

Comment: Yes it would be easier, I just copied some old code I had regarding this topic. And since the question doesn't state .NET framework version it would be easier to propose LINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I completely agree, but I think he was just trying to give a secondary solution because of the way the question was asked. Like answering `How can I pull a-b from z~ads~fsajljkfs~rasdo~a-b?`, GetFileName wouldn't help there.

Comment: @NickFreeman: I've edited my answer to answer his original question. I think `Substring(LastIndexOf('/'))` is the most efficient but unsafe approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wish I could upvote twice. Substring + LastIndexOf, is also a solution that can work in 2.0. The linq version is nice for 3.5+ if the split overhead is negotiable in your application.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Because msantodonato said 'I want to begin parsing from the end of the string and stop once I reach the first "/"'. Even though there is other options that is better, I was just answering his question.

Comment: .IndexOf is what I was looking for.  In addition to the pattern mentioned in my question, I also need to grab information from the middle and beginning of the string.  Since I am reading the string from a database table as opposed to the file system, I cannot use the Path class. This seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @MarcusSantodonato I don't understand. Why is this question tagged as `C#` if you can't use the path class?

Comment: @ nick Because my program is written in c#. The  list of filenames I am parsing is not coming from the file system so the path class is not going to help me. .indexof  allowed me to do what I needed to do.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class instead.

for example:

```
string path = "Some Directory/Some SubDirectory/SomeFile.pdf";
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vgOAOt)

**Edit**: just to answer you original question how to "read from right to left":

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) with [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx):

```
string fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vz0wW6)

(However, use the `Path` class if you work with paths)

Comment: Path is the single most under-utilized class in .NET. Everyone seams to think they should do that kind of parsing themselves.

Comment: @Cemafor I didn't know about Path.Combine for a long time. Wish I did, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using Path is best if you are actually treating it as file/folder information, but if you are treating it as a string that you just happen to want to split at '/' then you could Split then Reverse:

```
string str = "Some Directory/Some SubDirectory/SomeFile.pdf";
string[] terms = str.Split('/');
Array.Reverse(terms);
foreach (string term in terms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(term);
}
```

Comment: This prints:
`SomeFile.pdf`
`Some SubDirectory`
`Some Directory`
Not what is asked for.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I misread this: "I need to capture a substring for each item in a list of filepaths." (Besides, using the PathSeparator is just as  easy.)